# How do I create an uber jar in Ceylon

Tags: packaging, uberjar, ceylon

I have a Ceylon project. I would like to distribute it in an uber jar that includes all dependencies, so that it can be executed with simple

```
java -jar myproject.jar
```

Is this possible in Ceylon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming Ceylon 1.2.3 has the `fat-jar` subcommand. See https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/issues/5932 which tracks this feature. To use it now, you need to download a nightly build from http://ceylon-lang.org/download/ or build Ceylon yourself.

With Ceylon 1.2.3, assuming your module is called `myproject`, you can do

```
ceylon-1.2.3/bin/ceylon fat-jar myproject
java -jar myproject-1.0.0.jar
```

This executes code in function `run()` in file `source/myproject/run.ceylon`.

The uberjar for a simple hello world program has currently 2.4 MiB.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ceylon Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/ceylon-gradle-plugin#running-ceylon-code-without-the-ceylon-tool-in-the-jvm) can do it for you, just use the `createJavaRuntime` task:

```
gradle createJava
```

Run the application with:

```
bash build/java-runtime/run.sh
```

or the equivalent in your OS.

If you copy the `java-runtime` directory to a machine that has no Ceylon installed, only the JVM, it will work.

It's not a fat jar, but you can distribute this as a zip and get most of the same benefits.